# How to Exit Through Multiple Exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, exit

```
def directories():
    print("Creating STRaitRazor directories...")
    try:
        os.chdir("C:\\")
        os.mkdir("STRaitRazor")
        os.chdir("STRaitRazor")
        os.mkdir("Analysis")
        os.chdir("Analysis")
        os.mkdir("config")
        os.mkdir("fastq")
        os.chdir("..")
        os.mkdir("bin")
        os.chdir("bin")
        print("STRaitRazor directories successfully created")
        Sevenzip()
    except:
        print("Could not create directories. Do directories already exist?")
        response = input("Y/N\n")
        if response == "Y" or response == "y":
            Sevenzip()
        elif response == "N" or response == "n":
            print("Unexpected exception occurred, aborting...")
            time.sleep(5)
            sys.exit(1)

def Sevenzip():
    os.chdir("C:\\STRaitRazor\\bin")
    try:
        print("Downloading 7zip into C:\\STRaitRazor\\bin...")
        url = "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900.exe"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "7zip.exe")
        path = "C:/STRaitRazor/bin/"
        subprocess.call("7zip.exe /S /D=%s"%path)
        print("7zip downloaded")
        gitdownload()
    except:
        print("Could not download 7-zip. Check your internet connection and admin permissions.")
        response = input("Press ENTER to exit...")
        sys.exit(1)
```

I'm having an issue with actually being able to exit my program after an exception. A sample of my code is above.

Basically what I'm doing is nesting functions inside other functions because this program needs to do several things in a specific order, so I'm starting at the top, checking to see if the function executed properly, and, if so, move onto to the next function.

My issue is with the exceptions. Everytime an exception is raised, the program doesn't exit when I tell it to. Instead, it raises the exception it should, then goes up a level and raises that exception and so on and so forth until it finally quits.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Is it the way I've nested the functions?

Is there a way to force a program to quit no matter where the `sys.exit(1)` line is written?

Comment: Have you tried using `raise`?

Comment: `sys.exit` works by raising the `SystemExit` exception ... Because you have a bare `except` instead of `except SomeExceptionType`, you're exception handling is actually catching the `SystemExit`.  The minimal change to get the `sys.exit` to be respected would be `except Exception: ...`, but better would be to only catch the exceptions that you _expect_ to be raised and want to catch.

Comment: @mgilson Please don't post answers in the comments. Post it as an answer please and thanks. LMK when you do and I'll upvote.

Comment: It would help a lot if you provided a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

`sys.exit` works by raising the `SystemExit` exception.  Because you have a bare `except` instead of except `SomeHypotheticalExceptionType`, your exception handling is actually catching the `SystemExit`.

The minimal change to get the `sys.exit` to be respected would be `except Exception:`, but that isn't the *best* thing to do.  It would be much better to only catch the exceptions that you expect to be raised and know how to handle.  This is a generally accepted best-practice in python and it helps to avoid masking all sorts of nasty bugs that would otherwise go unnoticed (Imagine if you had misspelled the name of a variable -- surely you want the `NameError` to tell you that you did something wrong so you can fix it).